# html how to visually show a div inside its sibling div

Tags: html, css

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="c1">This is c1</div>
  <div class="c2">This is c2</div>
  <div class="c3">This is c3</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to visually show

1. c3.div inside c1.div
2. c3.div is center inside c1.div

Comment: CSS can not move the element to a different position in the DOM. But the "inside" part could probably be _faked_, visually - depending on what exactly you want this to look like, resp. what _in visual terms_ would constitute "inside" by your definition.

Comment: Do you mean to [absolute](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/#absolute) property?

Comment: Hi @CBroe, Yeah,I would like to visually fake it ."Inside"mean i would like to get a feel of <div class="c1"><div class="c3"></div></div>

Comment: Hi @groophylifefor , if possible to achieve this with absolute property, it would be helpful

Answer (score -1):

> Hi @groophylifefor , if possible to achieve this with absolute property, it would be helpful

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.parent > * {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="c1">This is c1</div>
  <div class="c2">This is c2</div>
  <div class="c3">This is c3</div>
</div>
```

###### Here it is all intertwined and it may be what you are looking for, but you have not explained what you want very well.